# sequelize: How to query with where on association primaryKey without creating join

Tags: sequelize.js

Model:

**album.js**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Album', {
        id: {
            field: 'AlbumID',
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            field: 'Name',
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'Album',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                models.Album.hasMany(models.Image, {
                    as: 'images',
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'AlbumID'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

**image.js**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Image', {
        id: {
            field: 'ImageID',
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        url: {
            field: 'Url',
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        title: {
            field: 'Title',
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'Image',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                models.Image.belongsTo(models.Album, {
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'AlbumID'
                    },
                    as: 'album'
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The questions is how can I get the following SQL?

`SELECT * FROM Image WHERE AlbumID = 1;`

The only thing that I was able to do is the following:

```
Image.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Album,
        as: 'album',
        where: {
            id: 1
        }
    }]
});
```

But unfortunately this creates a JOIN between Album and Image tables, which is really not necessary and impacts performance.

How can I perform query with FK ID in where condition, but without doing the join with FK table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply query it as

```
Image.findAll({
    where: {
        AlbumID: 1
    }
});
```

Foreign keys should be automatically added as a "valid" column name for querying.

Comment: This works. However, it does not look correct to mix model properties and actual column names. I am creating mappings so that I can have some way of decoupling, so I would prefer an option where I do not have to use "AlbumID" column name, but rather some mapped name like "partnerId" or "partner.id" or something along those lines. Is there any other way that does not require actual column names in the sequelize query?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You could, however, define a scope in the model definition so that you could query the image like `Image.scope({{ method: ['album', 1]}).findAll();`. For reference, [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/scopes)'s the documentation page.